# Have I shown that $D_{2n} = \langle a,b\mid a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^n = 1\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

From Dummit and Foote, section 1.2:

> Show that $\langle a,b\mid a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^n = 1\rangle$ gives a presentation for $D_{2n}$ in terms of the two generators $a=s$ and $b=sr$ of order 2 computed in Exercise 3 above.

Background on Exercise 3: In it we proved that $D_{2n}$ is generated by $s$ and $sr$, both of which have order $2$. \
Background on $D_{2n}$: Our usual presentation for the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is $D_{2n} = \langle r,s\mid r^n = s^2 = 1, rs=sr^{-1}\rangle$.

My attempt:

> We show that each set of relations follows from the other.
>
> From exercise 3, we recognize that $a=s$ and $b=sr$ satisfy the set of relations in this question's presentation.
>
> Likewise we see that $s=a$ and $r=ab$ satisfy the standard relations $s^2 = r^n = 1$ and $$rs = (ab)a = a(ba) = a(b^{-1}a^{-1}) = a(ab)^{-1} = sr^{-1}$$ where $a=a^{-1}$ and $b=b^{-1}$ follows from the fact that $a$ and $b$ have order at most $2$.
>
> Thus the two presentations are equivalent.

Is this all the question is asking for?  This seems a bit too trivial.

Comment: In case when one of the groups is finite this is enough. Because what you've shown that there is an epimorphism in both directions.

Comment: The dihedral groups are finite.  We've already shown that $|D_{2n}| = 2n$. So alright, thanks!